# log(log(123456789101112131415...)))

Tags: number-theory, logarithms

How would you fin the integer closest to

log(log(1234567891011121314...2013))

where the number is the concatenation of numbers 1 through 2013 inclusive.
log() in this case is log base 10.

Also, how would you find the remainder when it is divided by 75?

Comment: How would you find the closest integer? Are there restrictions on what you can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if a positive integer $n$ has $d$ digits in its decimal expansion then
$$d-1 \le \log(n) \le d$$
For example $\log(1529) = 3.1844\dots$ and $1529$ has $4$ digits.

How many digits are in $12345678 \dots 2013$? Well we have

- $9$ one-digit numbers
- $99-9=90$ two-digit numbers
- $999-99=900$ three-digit numbers
- $2013-999=1014$ four-digit numbers

So your number has $9 \times 1 + 90 \times 2 + 900 \times 3 + 1014 \times 4 = 6945$ digits.

So we must have
$$6944 \le \log(12345678 \dots 2013) \le 6945$$
and so $\log(6944) \le \log(\log(12345678\dots 2013)) \le \log(6945)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So log(log) is between 3 and 4. Which one is it closer to though?

Comment: @user2612743: $6944$ and $6945$ are small enough that we can just calculate their log. Alternatively, if you know the value of $\log 2$ and $\log 3$ then you can use the very crude bounds $\log(4000) \le \cdots \le \log(9000)$ together with laws of logarithms to get a good estimate. [Note that $4000=2^2 \times 10^3$ and so on.] It will come out that $\log(4000) > 3.5$.